# Why did SCSS code stop working in VS Code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I’m building a website on VS Code consisting of HTML and SCSS code. When I open the website on Google Chrome, using the Live Server extension for VS Code or from the file on my computer, it should show all the changes I made to HTML and SCSS. However, only HTML changes show up in the browser. Any changes made to SCSS don’t show up. This problem started about two weeks ago. Before then, all changes to SCSS were showing up without issue.

I’ve tried opening the project with Live Server and from my file on my computer, a hard refresh on Google Chrome, reinstalling the Live Server extension on VS Code, and updating VS Code. None of these steps solved the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you turned out an option of Live Server to watch for changes or include your SCSS files?

Comment: Are you compiling your LESS to CSS and then linking to that CSS file in your HTML?